# is there solve for this Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

when I launch with code i faced this problem 
Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.

my code

app.js
 '''

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect } from 'react-redux'

class App extends Component {

 increase = ()=>{
this.setState({
 count: this.state.count + 1
})
}
 decrease = ()=>{
this.setState({
  count :this.state.count - 1
})
}

  render(){
        return (


    <div>
    <button onClick={this.increase}>+</button>
    <div> {this.props.count}</div>
    <button onClick={this.decrease}>-</button>

    </div>

  );
  }

}
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    count:state.count
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

'''
rootReducer.js
'''
const initState ={
    count : 0
}

const reducer = (state = initState , action)=>{
    return state;
}
export default reducer;
```

rootReducer.js

```
 const initState ={
        count : 0
    }

    const reducer = (state = initState , action)=>{
        return state;
    }
    export default reducer;
```

i change it but still display for me that message, I created store file and put in it this code

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'; 
import {reducer , initialState } from './reducer';
 export const ConfigureStore =()=>
{ const store = createStore( reducer, initialState );
 return store
 }
```

and put provider in app  but still display message error any other solution for this problem?

Comment: I think you must use the Provider higher component in order to pass in the store to be used in your application, like in this example in the Redux docs: https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider#example-usage

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As explained in error message. You should wrap your root component of app with `Provider` Component from `react-redux`.
It should look like this

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

export default function App(){
 return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
      <Provider />);
}
```

`./store.js` should have store created with reducers and middlerwares(if any).

Comment: i change it  but still display for me that message, I created store file  and put in it this code ` import  {createStore} from 'redux';
import {reducer , initialState } from './reducer';

export const ConfigureStore =()=>{
    const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        initialState
    );
    return store
}` and put provider in app  any  other solution for this problem?

Comment: @MahmoudKhdre Everything else seems fine. can you share snippet where you have wrapped in provider as well ?